# SVN client installation in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have installed SVN Subversion in Ubuntu. And I can create a Repository and add the files in it and checkout from the Subversion.

But I need a SVN client (like TortoiseSVN client which is used in windows) to access SVN client.

Do we have any SVN client like the TortoiseSVN client in Ubuntu where I can access the SVN Server.

And I want to have a SVN Client which doesn't have a GUI interface, because the Ubuntu machine I am using it does not have GUI interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to create repositories and checkout from subversion repositories, you already have an SVN client.

I find your two statements a little contradictory - you "need an SVN client like Tortoise SVN on windows" but it "should not have a GUI". Perhaps it would help if you explained what you are trying to do.

Also, how did you install SVN on you ubuntu machine?

Comment: @shanth: I installed SVN subversion using Putty. and the machine i am using dosenot have GUI interface. so what ever i have to install, i have to install thorugh putty using unix commands. and i gave an exmaple like " Totoise SVN is used in windows.. does we have any SVN clients in Ubuntu"???..that was my question..

Comment: "using putty" is not the answer i'm looking for. I'm looking for something like "using the command apt-get" - so how did you install SVN?

Answer (score 0):

If you on't want a gui, you can simply use [svn command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/svn)